# Merge with Unique filtered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2008-r2, filtered-index

So I've discovered a strange SQL Server behavior today.

Suppose I have a table like this, id is primary key

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name ║ active ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ a    ║      0 ║
║  2 ║ a    ║      1 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╝
```

And suppose I have a `filtered unique index on name where active = 1`.
Now, I just want to **switch active for rows**, set first row inactive and set second row active. When I try to do update it like

```
update Table1 set 
    active = n.active
from Table1 as t
inner join (values (1, 1), (2, 0)) as n(id, active) on n.id = t.id
```

it **works fine**. But if I try to do merge:

```
merge Table1 as t
using (values (1, 1), (2, 0)) as n(id, active) on n.id = t.id
when matched then
    update set active = n.active;
```

if **failed** with error `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Table1' with unique index 'ix_Table1'. The duplicate key value is (a)`.

Even stranger, if I have table like this (first row have active = 1 and second row have active = 0):

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name ║ active ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ a    ║      1 ║
║  2 ║ a    ║      0 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╝
```

and merge it like this:

```
merge Table1 as t
using (values (1, 0), (2, 1)) as n(id, active) on n.id = t.id
when matched then
    update set active = n.active;
```

It **works fine** again. So it really looks like merge does updates **row by row** and checking indexe after each row. I've checked unique constraints, unique indexes without filter, it' all work ok. It only failes when I combine merge and filtered index.

So the question is - is it a bug and if it is, what's the best workaround for this?

You can try it on **[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50478/1)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this article on sqlblog.com - [MERGE Bug with Filtered Indexes](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/12/10/merge-bug-with-filtered-indexes.aspx), it's written by [Paul White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440595/paul-white), dated 2012.

He gave a couple of workarounds:

> - Adding all columns referenced in the filtered index’s WHERE clause to the index key (INCLUDE is not sufficient); or
> - Executing the query with trace flag 8790 set e.g. OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8790).

After a bit of research I've found that if I add primary key column into update, it works ok, so the query becomes:

```
merge Table1 as t
using (values (1, 1), (2, 0)) as n(id, active) on n.id = t.id
when matched then
    update set active = n.active, id = n.id;
```

I think that it's also possible to add column from updted index, but haven't tested it yet.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50478/6)</kbd>**